# html.erbでのコメントアウトの方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Ruby on Railsを独学しているのですが、
html.erbでのコメントアウトの記述方法が分かりません。

```
<tbody>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
  <!-- ここから
    <td><%= user.id %></td>  
    <td><%= user.title %></td>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
  ここまで、コメントアウトしたいです。
  -->
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

上記のようなコードで、
対象のエリアを<%#= %>も含めてコメントアウトしたいとき、
どのようにコーディングすべきでしょうか。

試しに以下のようなことも試みたのですが、エラーになりました。

```
<tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
    <!-- ここから
      <td><%= #user.id %></td>
      <td><%= #user.title %></td>
      <td><%= #user.name %></td>
      ここまで、コメントアウトしたいです。
    -->
    </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 本家 Stack Overflow 上の関連質問です: ["Block comments in html.erb templates in rails"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127644/5989200)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ERB におけるブロック・コメントにはいくつか方法があります。

1. `<%# ... %>` や `<%#= ... %>` を使う方法

   ```
   <%#
      ...
   %>
   ```
2. Ruby の複数行コメント `=begin` ... `=end` を使う方法

   ```
   <% =begin %>
      ...
   <% =end %>
   ```
3. `if false` で囲う方法 (厳密にはコメントではありませんが、ある程度コメントのように振る舞います。)

   ```
   <% if false %>
      ...
   <% end %>
   ```

なお、`<!-- ... -->` でも HTML のコメント・アウトはできますが、出力に表れてしまいます。

---

#### 参考

- [ビュー(view)](http://railsdoc.com/view) -- Railsドキュメント (下の方にコメントについて言及があります)
- ["Block comments in html.erb templates in rails"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127644/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
- ["How to comment lines in rails html.erb files?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3901619/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
- ["How do I comment out ERB in Rails?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8514946/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

Comment: <%#= %>を使ってコメントアウトできました。有難うございます!!